# How to move jquery ui in to the footer to wordperss?

Tags: jquery

I am able to move jquery ui in the footer but i want to move it between the footer scripts (above all js scripts).

here is the code i used to load jquery in the footer.

```
if (!is_admin()) add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "wpf_CybarMagazine_scripts", 11);
function wpf_CybarMagazine_scripts() {

wp_deregister_script('jquery');
 wp_register_script('jquery', "http" . ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443 ? "s" : "") . "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js", false, '1.11.1', true);
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

}
```

html output is....

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/demo/CybarMagazine/wp-includes/js/admin-bar.min.js?ver=4.0.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/demo/CybarMagazinehttp//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/demo/CybarMagazine/wp-content/themes/CybarMagazine/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
```

I want to load the jquery library in top, but i can't find any solution for moving the jquery between footer scripts. Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quickfix.

Try this:

```
 wp_register_script('jquery', "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js", false, '1.11.1', true);
```

Update:

Let's split this string into 3 parts:

- "http"
- ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443 ? "s" : "")
- "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js", false, '1.11.1', true);

---

- "http" - We don't need beucase jQuery starts with //
- This is if/else statemnt which was causing the problem, it was adding `localhost/demo/CybarMagazinehttp` to your output results
- This what link to jQuery DNS which we want to leave without changes

Comment: wow man it solved! can you told me what was the problem with previous link?